# vuejs custom directive does not seem to register

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am building custom directive, it is stored in its own file

autosize.js and it looks like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import autosize from 'autosize'

Vue.directive('autosize', {
    bind: function() {
        console.log('autosize bind')
        var self = this
            Vue.nextTick(function() {
            autosize(self.el)
        })
    },

    update: function(value) {
        console.log('autosize update')
        var self = this
        Vue.nextTick(function() {
            self.el.value = value
            autosize.update(self.el)
        })
    },

    unbind: function() {
        autosize.destroy(this.el)
    }
})
```

I use it inside file component and import it like this:

```
import Autosize  from 'components/directives/autosize.js'
```

register it like this:

```
        directives: {
            Autosize
        }
```

Inside my file component i try to use it like this :

```
<textarea v-autosize="input" :value="input" @input="update" class="form-control">{{input}}</textarea>
```

Autosize is a plugin that is supposed to make textarea grow, ofcourse nothing happens when i test adding more text. But it seems that its not autosize that fails to work but perhaps I have missed something, not even these get printed:

```
console.log('autosize bind')

console.log('autosize update')
```

when I dynamically create the component.

Anyone has an idea what I have missed so that directive is not binding or updating?

Comment: In Vue 2, the typical way to work with code like this is using a wrapper component. But as far as this directive is concerned, `el` is passed in as an argument in directives, it's not available using `this` (or `this` renamed as `self`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You typically wrap libraries like this with a wrapper component in Vue 2. Here is an example `autosize` component.

```
const AutoSize = {
  props:["value"],
  template: `<textarea v-model="internalValue"></textarea>`,
  computed:{
    internalValue:{get(){return this.value}, set(v){this.$emit('input', v)}}
  },
  mounted(){ autosize(this.$el)},
  beforeDestroy(){ autosize.destroy(this.$el) }
}
```

Here is a working example.

```js
console.clear()

const AutoSize = {
  props:["value"],
  template: `<textarea v-model="internalValue"></textarea>`,
  computed:{
    internalValue:{get(){return this.value}, set(v){this.$emit('input', v)}}
  },
  mounted(){ autosize(this.$el)},
  beforeDestroy(){ autosize.destroy(this.$el) }
}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components:{autosize: AutoSize}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/autosize@4.0.0"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2"></script>
<div id="app">
  Paste a large amount of text:
  <hr>
  <autosize></autosize>
</div>
```

But if you really wanted to use a directive, as I mentioned in my comment to your question, `el` is a parameter to the directive hooks. Here is a working directive.

```
Vue.directive("autosize", {
  bind(el){ autosize(el) },
  inserted(el) { autosize.update(el) },
  update(el){ autosize.update(el) },
  unbind(el){ autosize.destroy(el) }
})
```

```js
console.clear()

Vue.directive("autosize", {
  bind(el){ autosize(el) },
  inserted(el) { autosize.update(el) },
  update(el){ autosize.update(el) },
  unbind(el){ autosize.destroy(el) }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/autosize@4.0.0"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2"></script>
<div id="app">
  Paste a large amount of text:
  <hr>
  <textarea v-autosize cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
</div>
```

If you included that directive as is in your `components/directives/autosize.js` file, without exporting it, I would expect it to work because `Vue.directive` registers directives globally. If you *wanted* to register it locally then the file should look like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import autosize from 'autosize'

export default {
  bind(el){ autosize(el) },
  inserted(el) { autosize.update(el) },
  update(el){ autosize.update(el) },
  unbind(el){ autosize.destroy(el) }
}
```

Comment: Hi Bert, in that last example you export without using Vue.directive, is that correct or you forgot to add it? How would Vue now know that it's dealing with directive?

Comment: @maxit I didn't forget it. In the component where you want to use it, you would `import autosize from "components/directives/autosize.js"` and then you would have `directives: { autosize: autosize}` in the component. This is only if you wanted to *locally* register the directive. `Vue.directive` *globally* registers it.